# How to compress two audio samples to be equally loud with librosa?

Tags: python, librosa

I'm trying to make two audio samples as similar as possible and my problem is that in one test-case their loudness isn't similar enough.

```
data1, sr1 = librosa.load(path_1, sr=None)
data2, sr2 = librosa.load(path_2, sr=None)
```

Here are my plots of `data1` and `data2` over time (s) - you can see `data1` is a bit quieter at the beginning:
[image: Original]
I thought I just have to normalize it, but then I realized librosa is already doing that on `load`.
So the problem seems to be, that the quieter parts are louder in `data2` than in `data1`.

That sounds like a compression thing to me, so I tried to compress `data1`:

```
 data1, sr1 = librosa.load(path_1, sr=None)
 data1 = librosa.mu_compress(data1, quantize=False)
 data2, sr2 = librosa.load(path_2, sr=None)
```

[image: compressed_data1]

Unfortunately now `data1`'s quiet parts are too loud.
So I tried to compress data2 too:

```
data1, sr1 = librosa.load(path_1, sr=None)
data1 = librosa.mu_compress(data1, quantize=False)
data2, sr2 = librosa.load(path_2, sr=None)
data2 = librosa.mu_compress(data2, quantize=False)
```

[image: both compressed]
But then I'm back where I began...
I hope I made my problem clear ;)

How to compress the sounds the 'smart way' so that they both end up as similar as possible?

Comment: How are you comparing the audio samples?

Comment: What is the time axis in the plots? Seconds?

Comment: Loudness normalization and adaptive gain control are keywords here. "Compress" is probably not relevant, as it has other meanings